# How to make this program repeat until the user decides to terminate?

Tags: c++

How can I make this program repeat until the user decides to terminate to program, I want the program to ask the user if he/she wants to repeat it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int dec_num, r;
    string hexdec_num = "";
    char hex[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };
    cout << "\n\n Convert a decimal number to hexadecimal number:\n";
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << " Input a decimal number: ";
    cin >> dec_num;

    while (dec_num > 0)
    {
        r = dec_num % 16;
        hexdec_num = hex[r] + hexdec_num;
        dec_num = dec_num / 16;
    }
    cout << " The hexadecimal number is : " << hexdec_num << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Add another loop, surrounding the loop you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with nested while loops:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool play_again;
    do
    {
        // your code

        while (true) // loop asking user
        {
            string user_input;
            cout << "again? ('y', 'n'):" << endl;
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "y")
            {
                play_again = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (user_input == "n")
            {
                play_again = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
            }
        }
    } while (play_again);
}
```

You could also extract this logic into a separate function if you wanted to.